# Cannot remove the progress bar after the ajax call is completed

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

What am I doing wrong?

```
progressbar : function() { 
    var $progress = $('<div>', {'class' : 'progress-bar', height : '2px'});
    var width = 0,
        load  = 0;
    $(document).on({ 
        ajaxSend : function(event, req, set) {
            $('body').append($progress);            
            load = setInterval(function(e) {
                if (width > 100) {
                    clearInterval(load);
                }
                width++;
                $('.progress-bar').width(width + '%');
            }, 10);
        },
        ajaxComplete : function(){
            width = 0;
            clearInterval(load);
            $('body').remove('.progress-bar');
            //$('.progress-bar').fadeOut();
        }
    });
}
```

The fadeOut function works but I cannot remove the .progress-bar from the DOM. I call the above function on window - load & click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `$('.progress-bar').remove()`

Comment: @krasenslavov Glad, I helped. DO accept the answer for future reference to others :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$('body').remove('.progress-bar');
```

replace this with

```
$('.progress-bar').remove();
```